# Get index of element excluding determinate elements

Tags: jquery

I've got this HTML structure:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><i class="icon-remove"></i> file1</li>
    <li class="error"><i class="icon-remove"></i> file2</li>
    <li><i class="icon-remove"></i> file3</li>
</ul>
```

So now, when I click .icon-remove I want to know the index of his parent element (li) excluding (in the count) li.error.

I tried with this:

```
$("#list li:not(.error) .icon-remove").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().index($("#list li:not(.error)")));
});
```

It returns correct index only for the first element (0). [You can check in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaniloPolani/sL2sB/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sL2sB/8/)

```
$("#list li:not(.error) .icon-remove").click(function () {
    var $lis = $(this).closest('ul').find('li:not(.error)'),
        $li = $(this).closest('li');
    alert($lis.index($li));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `closest` to find the `li` element.  Passing a selector to `index` doesn't behave as you expect it to.

```
$("#list li:not(.error) .icon-remove").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest("li").index());
});
```

From the [JQuery documentation for index](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

Comment: The problem is not with the general index, but getting the index excluding <li> with class 'error'.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#list li:not(.error) .icon-remove").click(function() {
            alert($('ul#list > li').not('.error').index($(this).parent()));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li><i class="icon-remove">remove</i> file1</li>
    <li class="error"><i class="icon-remove">remove</i> file2</li>
    <li><i class="icon-remove">remove</i> file3</li>
</ul>
```